# Android, understanding AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Are specific AsyncTask's for specific activities? Or could I have say a RESTful APIManager which called one of four AsyncTask Classes, APIGET APIPOST APIPUT APIDELETE and be able to handle the network code that way? My idea is to be able to call something like this throughout my UI code.

```
<edit> Class UserPrefs;
APIManager.createUser(JSONObject info);

APIManager.createUser {
    // handle info
    APIPost newPost = new APIPost(info);
}

APIPost extends AsyncTask {
    doInBackground {
         //network code
         <edit> UserPrefs.save(result);
    }

}
```

Would this model be possible? Or am I misusing AsyncTask?

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTasks are a natural fit for a RESTful service, but they are not tied to the lifecycle of Activities. You may create and start an Async task, but by the time the task finishes its background work and calls onPostExecute, the originating activity no longer exists in memory. Because of this, you should have a better plan for how to store local data than to keep it in an Activity member, where it can and will disappear frequently. To avoid thrashing, you should save the data somewhere. Candidates for saving local data are SharedPreferences, the file system, a database or the Application singleton object depending on the nature of the data and your app.

Comment: So if I have a static UserPreferences class to save to which will handle SharedPreferences info for the user then this is possible?

Comment: Sure, you can keep your data there. You can keep it wherever you want. I'm just pointing out that it what the AsyncTask returns in onPostExecute will be lost if you don't save it _somewhere_ and the Activity is a bad place for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), AsyncTasks are using it internally. Very easy to use.